# Rename mesh as per group name(issue with shape node'unique name')

Tags: python, maya

I am working on a python script(maya3d software) to 'rename mesh as per group name'. After running the script an error is coming maybe because I have same shape node name in two groups. Here's the error message:

> Error: RuntimeError: file  line 8: More than one object matches name

The script is working fine if the object is with a unique name. I found something to `ignoreShape` in rename page, but it's not working.
Here's the link: https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/CommandsPython/rename.html?&_ga=2.14607159.1860356590.1585850032-633810306.1580653271#flagignoreShape

[image]

Here's the script:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

import maya.cmds as cmds

selection = cmds.ls( selection=True )
for each in selection:
    groupName = cmds.ls(each, selection=True )
    children = cmds.listRelatives(groupName, children=True)  
    for count,obj in enumerate(children):
        cmds.rename(obj,groupName[0]+str(count+1).zfill(2)+'_GEO')


selection = cmds.ls( selection=True )
for each in selection:
    groupName = cmds.ls(each, selection=True )
    children = cmds.listRelatives(groupName, children=True) 
    for child in children:
        newname=child.replace('_GRP','_')
        cmds.rename(child,newname)
```

Can anybody help me with this, please.
Thanks.

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code sample.

Comment: added indentation..while copy those were removed...

Comment: This often is a result of a non absolute name. You can try `ls(sl=True, l=True)` to get the long name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the modified code:

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds

selection = cmds.ls(selection=True)
# group_name will contain the group name, no need to query again
for group_name in selection:
    # The key is to query the full path, so you'll get
    # "|aa_GRP|pCube1" (which is unique) instead of "pCube1" (which is not)
    children = cmds.listRelatives(group_name, children=True, fullPath=True)
    for i, obj in enumerate(children, start=1):
        cmds.rename(obj, '{group}{number:02}_GEO'.format(
            group=group_name,
            number=i))
```